# Add a condition on dropdown selection

Tags: 8, rules

I have a dropdown in a node and the id of the dropdown is "field_b_status".
I want to add condition in a rule if the drop down value is equals to one of the value "Complete" then send email.

When i try to add that, i see the error.
**Data selector field_b_status.value for context Data to compare is invalid. Unable to get variable field_b_status, it is not defined.**
Please see the screenshot:
[image]

Can you please help me how to add dropdown "field_b_status" in the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) in Drupal 8 doesn't have much flexibility.
So in your case, you will do the following to achieve it.

Under Data selector, you will type: **{{node.field_b_status.value}}** and choose Direct mode instead.

And rest will be similar to your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `field_b_status.value` is not a valid value in the data selector. I guarantee that it does NOT show up in the autocomplete for the data selector. Why? Because it is not fully qualified. If you want a field value, you need to also specify the entity that the field belongs to.

The solution is, when using the data selector, choose one of the values listed in the autocomplete for the data selector - DO NOT type in your own value. What you want to select is probably something like `node.field_b_status`, or `node.field_b_status.value`, depending on what type of field `field_b_status` is, whether it's a single-valued or multiple-valued field, and depending on how the event provides the entity context (I assume it's something like "node", but it doesn't have to be ...).